# How do i Copy source to target bean with fewer properties in target using BeanUtils?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I guess Beanutils.copyProperties() throws exception on copying from source to target with a property that does not exist in target. String[] ignoreList parameter only ignores properties that exist in target, it seems. 
Is there any way to ignore some of the source properties ?
Any help is humbly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ***copyProperties(...)*** method from [BeanUtilsBean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/index.html?org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) instead, its much better designed. Alternatively you can take a look at [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html).

Comment: Thanks, i am going to try this. Seems like obtaining Map using BeanUtils.describe and removing properties also does the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you could choose whatever answer was most helpful to you by placing a check mark next to it, that would be great for the wiki.